Deriving the Equality for $ \mathbf{U}^\top [\mathbf{u}_3]_\times \boldsymbol{\omega}^* [\mathbf{u}_3]_\times \mathbf{U} $
I am trying to verify the derivation of the following expression involving a skew-symmetric matrix $ [\mathbf{u}_3]_\times $, a symmetric matrix $ \boldsymbol{\omega}^* $ representing a cross-product in a matrix form, and an orthogonal matrix $ \mathbf{U} $:
$$
\mathbf{U}^\top [\mathbf{u}_3]_\times \boldsymbol{\omega}^* [\mathbf{u}_3]_\times \mathbf{U} = \begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbf{u}_2 & -\mathbf{u}_1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}^\top 
\boldsymbol{\omega}^* 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbf{u}_2 & -\mathbf{u}_1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Here’s the context:

$\mathbf{u}_i$ is the i-th column of the matrix $\mathbf{U}$
$ \mathbf{U} $ is orthogonal ($ \mathbf{U}^\top \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{I} $).
$ [\mathbf{u}_3]_\times $ is the skew-symmetric matrix for the vector $ \mathbf{u}_3 = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \end{bmatrix} $, defined as:
$$
   [\mathbf{u}_3]_\times = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & -u_3 & u_2 \\
   u_3 & 0 & -u_1 \\
   -u_2 & u_1 & 0
   \end{bmatrix}.
   $$
$ \boldsymbol{\omega}^* $ is a symmetric matrix.

The relationship is given in Hartley and Zisserman’s Multiple View Geometry, equation (19.20).
My Question:
Could someone provide the step-by-step derivation for this transition:

Hint: Since the columns of $U$ are an orthonormal basis for ${\mathbb R}^3$
$$\eqalign{
u_i\cdot u_j &= \delta_{ij} \
u_i\times u_j &= \pm u_k \
}$$

@Rowing Also, note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions on this site. Please [edit] your question to tell us your thoughts on the problem and what you've tried so far.

@Rowing As a further hint: note that
$$
([\mathbf u_3]\times \mathbf U)^\top = \mathbf U^\top [\mathbf u_3]{\times}^\top = \mathbf U^\top (-[\mathbf u_3]\times) = -\mathbf U^\top [\mathbf u_3]\times.
$$
So, once you have an expression for $[\mathbf u_3]_\times \mathbf U$, you can plug in to get what you're after

@Rowing Your formula is wrong: you seem to be missing a minus-sign. A correct formula is
$$
\mathbf{U}^\top [\mathbf{u}3]\times \boldsymbol{\omega}^* [\mathbf{u}3]\times \mathbf{U} = -\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{u}_2 & -\mathbf{u}_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^\top
\boldsymbol{\omega}^*
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{u}_2 & -\mathbf{u}_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

@greg and Ben Thank you so much, I could solve it now! And sorry, I'll describe my attempt next time!
